# Python logging library - log messages which have double quotes in it

Tags: python, python-logging

I am using python logging library with simpleFormatter to log messages. This is that I have in my `config.ini` file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format={"@timestamp": "%(asctime)s", "message": "%(message)s"}
propagate=False
```

I have a requirement where I need to preserve both backslashes and double quotes in log messages. Example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(os.path.basename(__file__))
logger.info("test \"log\" msg")
```

**Output:**

```
{"@timestamp": "2021-09-29 11:59:57,656", "message": "test "log" msg"}
```

**Expected log message:**

```
{"@timestamp": "2021-09-29 11:59:57,656", "message": "test \"log\" msg"}
```

How can I get simpleFormatter to treat the message as raw string? I tried `format={"@timestamp": "%(asctime)s", "message": "%(message)r"}` but that didn't help. Any other suggestions?

P.S: I tried using a few 3rd party libraries for formatters like logstash-python-formatter, I am able to get the expected output but none of them provide the ability to control what fields show up in the log (I just need timestamp, message and few other fields). If there is any library which enables users to customize fields, that will help too.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for try `print(r'test \"log\" msg')`

Comment: No, I want to output a json log using the logging library.

Comment: you can also use `logging.info(r'test \"log\" msg')`

Comment: Yes sure, that will work, but the logs are not always generated by the user, so we cannot expect another system will do that for us. It would be great if we can configure that in the .ini file's format somehow so that all messages are treated as raw by default.

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible. `"test \"log\" msg"` is being parsed as `'test "log" msg'` before any code even runs. It's not possible in python code to distinguish which of those two the user gave you.

Comment: Where are these messages coming from, exactly? If they're coming from a static file, you can make the string literal raw. If they're coming from programmatically generated content, then you're apparently receiving quote characters without preceding slashes. You can transform it afterwards to escape quotes for output, as in vvvv's answer. If that's not applicable to your problem, please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom `Formatter` for this purpose. This custom `MyFormatter` class overrides the `format` method and reworks the `record.msg` before formatting it with the correct `fmt` string.

```py
import logging

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg.replace('"', r'\"')
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
```

that you can use:

```
mylogger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mylogger.propagate = False

streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
streamhandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = MyFormatter(
    fmt="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)
streamhandler.setFormatter(formatter)

mylogger.addHandler(streamhandler)

mylogger.info("test \"log\" msg")
```

It logs:

```
2023-02-07 15:25:41,519 - INFO - test \"log\" msg
```